# QtConse in Spyder cannot use multiprocessing.Manager

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

If I open IPython QtConsole standalone and run the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
manager = Manager()
```

It worked fine. However, if I use the IPython Console inside Spyder, that specific console stopped responding.

I am using Windows 64 bit, Python 3.3.5 64 bit, Spyder 2.3.1.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using Windows 7 64-bit, Python 3.4.0, and Spyder 2.3.1.

Comment: @dano Thank you for the input! I just checked, and my Python 3.4.2 does not report this issue either. It seems to be specific to Python 3.3.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Too bad is not working for you but a) multiprocessing is known to have problems with IPython qtconsole, and b) we don't have the manpower to solve this for all Python versions. Fortunately it's working for 3.4 :)

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Hi Carlos! Thank you for your response - and also your every effort to keep this project going! I posted this thread to see whether I am doing something wrong, so I got my answer and good to know that I can get it back to work by upgrading to Python 3.4! :)

Comment: @ShawnWang glad you are a happy user and that this thread has helped you to keep things going :-)